# Use Geotrellis to rasterize LiDAR data

Tags: lidar, hive, geotrellis, hadoop-distributed-file-system

How can I use **Geotrellis** (distributed format) to **Rasterize LiDAR** (or XYZ DATA ) in HDFS?

I converted las file to spark RDD with the IQMULUS library and I want to use this RDD ( [x1,y1,z1] [x2,y2,z2] ....) to create a DEM with Geotrellis.

Comment: Are you working with raw las or lasd data to create a DEM or something similar? There's not enough detail in your post to tell what you're trying to do.

Comment: Yes, I converted las file to spark RDD with IQMULUS library and i want to use This RDD ( [x1,y1,z1]  [x2,y2,z2] ....) to DEM with Geotrellis .